# java if else statement

Tags: java

I am a new student who is trying to use java if else statements at the moment.

I have attched my class and i need to say if this code get 0 errors for all 4 errors(error11, error12, error13 and error14), need to display the text "Answer".
This code was working without the if else statements and there are 2 errors in those 2 lines.
Please explain me how to do it?

```
public static void deltaR()
 {
 int x;  
 int x11, x12, x13, x14;
 int x21, x22, x23, x24; //inputs

 double w10, w11, w12;//weights for first neuron
 int d11, d12, d13, d14;//desired output for first neuron
 double net11, net12, net13, net14;//sum of weights times inputs
 int y11, y12, y13, y14;//outputs
 int error11, error12, error13, error14;//error

 //double w20, w21, w22;//weights for second neuron
 //int d21, d22, d23, d24;//desired output for second neuron
 //double net21, net22, net23, net24;//sum of weights times input
 //int y21, y22, y23, y24;//outputs
 //int error21, error22, error23, error24;//error

 if (error11 = 0, error12 = 0, error13 = 0, error14 = 0)
 {
  System.out.println("Answer");
 }
 else if (error11 != 0, error12 != 0, error13 != 0, error14 != 0)
 {
 double coe=0.5;//learning coefficient
 x=1;

 x11=0;
 x12=0;
 x13=1;
 x14=1;

 x21=0;
 x22=1;
 x23=0;
 x24=1;

 d11= 0;
 d12= 1;
 d13= 0;
 d14= 1;

 w10=0.5;
 w11=-1;
 w12=1.5;

 net11=(x*w10 + x11*w11 + x21*w12);
 net12=(x*w10 + x12*w11 + x22*w12);
 net13=(x*w10 + x13*w11 + x23*w12);
 net14=(x*w10 + x14*w11 + x24*w12);

 if (net11>=0)
  y11=1;
 else
  y11=0;

 if (net12>=0) 
  y12=1;
 else
  y12=0;

 if (net13>=0)
  y13=1;
 else
  y13=0;

 if (net14>=0) 
  y14=1;
 else
  y14=0;

 error11=(d11-y11);
 error12=(d12-y12);
 error13=(d13-y13);
 error14=(d14-y14);

 System.out.println("net value 1:  "+net11);
 System.out.println("net value 2:  "+net12);
 System.out.println("net value 3:  "+net13);
 System.out.println("net value 4:  "+net14);

 System.out.println("output 1:  "+y11);
 System.out.println("output 2:  "+y12);
 System.out.println("output 3:  "+y13);
 System.out.println("output 4:  "+y14);

 System.out.println("error1:  "+error11);
 System.out.println("error2:  "+error12);
 System.out.println("error3:  "+error13);
 System.out.println("error4:  "+error14);
 }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use commas like that - you need to use [boolean logical operators](http://www.sap-img.com/java/java-boolean-logical-operators.htm).

If you want `or`, use `||`, if you want `and` use `&&`:

```
// If ANY of the error variables are 0 the if clause will execute
if(error11 == 0 || error12 == 0 || error13 == 0 || error14 == 0)

// If ALL of the error variables are 0 the if clause will execute
if(error11 == 0 && error12 == 0 && error13 == 0 && error14 == 0)
```

You are also using the assignment operator `=` instead of the equality operator `==`. You should read up on your [operators](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Additionally, if you always want the `else` clause to run when the `if` clause is incorrect, you do not need to add the second `if` conditional:

```
if(error11 == 0 || error12 == 0 || error13 == 0 || error14 == 0)
{
}
else
{
   // Code here will run if the above `if` clause evaluates to false
}
```

---

Not related to your question, but as a matter of style, naming your variables `x`, `y`, `d` and `w` (with the numbers or without) is bad practice - use more descriptive names and readability will increase.

Having numbers for related variables suggests that you should be using [arrays](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/arrays.doc.html).

```
int[] inputs = new int[9]; // inputs is an array of 9 integers
```

Comment: Were you expecting to use == instead of = ?

Comment: @Kumu - You are terminating the `if` with the `;` after the closing brace (`error14 == 0);`). That's incorrect syntax. Remove that `;`.

Answer (score 1):

When checking multiple conditions, you need to specify if it's an AND condition (`&&`) or an OR condition (`||`).

`||` will stop evaluating the boolean expression once it encounters a `true` expression, and return `true`, or return `false` otherwise. For example:

```
if (userIsMale || userIsFemale) { /* user is male OR female */ }
```

`&&` will stop evaluating the boolean expression once it encounters a `false` expression, and return `false`, or return `true` otherwise. For example:

```
if (userIsHuman && userIsMale) { /* user is human AND is male */ }
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers and now i changed it as the following  if (error11 == 0 && error12 == 0 && error13 == 0 && error14 == 0);
 {
  System.out.println("Answer");
 }
 else
 {}                                                                    Now it display the error                                     Syntax error on token "else", delete this token

 at Learn_1.deltaR(Learn_1.java:55) like this                                                                 Please anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

For mathematical comparisons you can use the following.

```
if (error11 == 0 && error12 == 0 && error13 == 0 && error14 == 0)
```

can be replaced with the following assuming errorXX is 0 or 1.

```
if (error11 + error12 + error13 + error14 == 0)
```

and

```
if (error11 == 0 || error12 == 0 || error13 == 0 || error14 == 0)
```

becomes

```
if (error11 * error12 * error13 * error14 == 0)
```

However, instead of using an int for true/false you should use a boolean. Thats what its for. e.g.

```
if (!(error11 || error12 || error13 || error14))
```

You can simplify the code so.

```
d11= 0;
net11=(x*w10 + x11*w11 + x21*w12);
if (net11>=0)
  y11=1;
else
  y11=0;

error11=(d11-y11);
System.out.println("error1:  "+error11);
```

becomes

```
double net11=(x*w10 + x11*w11 + x21*w12);
System.out.println("error1:  "+ (net11 >=0 ? -1 : 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using commas in `if` statements is impossible. You must use logical operators: `&&` which means `and`, and `||` which means `or`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to test for what it seems you want to test is:

```
if ((error11 | error 12 | error13 | error 14) == 0) { //all are zero
//...do stuff
} else if ((error11 & error12 & error13 & error14) != 0) { //all are not zero
//...do different stuff
}
```

this makes use of the integer bitwise operations.

However, your code seems to be missing the case for some errors are zero, some are not - or at least, that case does nothing.  If that case *shouldn't* be nothing, either add it's behavior with an `else` on the end or join it into one of the other cases by writing that case as an `else` instead of as an `if` test.

Answer (score 0):

learn about logical operation.. they are **OR** (||) **AND** (&&)  **EQUAL TO** (==) and **NOT** (!)

Comment: and DO NOT ADD ';' after if statement just if( bla bla ){ bla bla}